# Does the faction of your armor/clothes affect character interactions in Skryim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've killed off some well equipped Imperials, looted their bodies and want to equip their armor.  Does the game take into consideration that I look like an Imperial when I interact with pro-Imperial or anti-Imperial characters going forward?

Comment: Related mod: [Master of Disguise - Real Faction Armor - Faction Overhaul](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/45047/) "*...transforms all faction armor into real faction armor. Suit up as a Dark Brotherhood assassin, a Madman of the Reach, or even a lowly necromancer and experience Tamriel as though their allies, friends, and enemies were yours.*"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No one in the game refuses to speak to you based on what you're wearing.

They'll even talk to you if you're freezing your rear off, stark-naked, in front of them. (Though as Communist Duck points out, they do remark on it.)

#### Edit

I have found that the Captain of the Guards in Solitude gets offended if you walk around in Stormcloak armor. Instead of making generic "captain of the guard" comments, if you're wearing the Stormcloak armor, he'll accuse you of being a Stormcloak supporter. If you say to his face, in the Imperial Army's Headquarters, that you hate the Empire, he'll get understandably angry and attack you (though he accepts yields, so clearly he doesn't want to kill you *that* much...).

So in short, your outfit might add **additional** dialog options, but as far as I've been able to determine, it never precludes you from any.

This is different from New Vegas, where it *did* work like that, but remember, that game wasn't made by Bethesda.

Comment: If you're not wearing anything, people will actually comment on it.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck You're right. Updated.

Comment: To add to this, I was wearing full Imperial Armor with Imperial Officer Helmet, and a guard in Whiterun commented on how nice my set of Imperial Armor looked.

Comment: So the affect of wearing clothes and armor that belong to a specific group is limited to the offhand comments characters make, but not anything substantial to the game or choices you get?

Comment: @sXe I've updated my answer to have more info. Generally, I think that's right.

Comment: I initially thought it was like Fallout:New Vegas, so I stored Stormcloak and Imperial armor in my inventory and changed armor depending on who I am dealing with. Thanks to this, I will now wear my Dark Brotherhood armor everwhere. Muahahahaha!!

Comment: I've had people remark that I looked sneaky, or that I better keep my hands to myself. I'm not sure if this is due to my skills or the thieves guild armor I'm wearing. I'll update when I get more info.

Comment: But does wearing the wrong factions armour or no armour effect your effective speechcraft? i.e. does my chance to persuade or intimidate change, or can I sell items for as much in no/different armour?

Comment: @Arkive The sneaky and hands to yourself comments are due to your high sneak skill.  You get similar comments about your abilities if you have high magic skills (usually people fearful of your magic) or combat skills