# Which clothes are you punished for in the cities of Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

There are certain clothes in Skyrim you can get a bounty for if worn, this is why I try to be rather neutrally clothed. I know that if you enter a Stormcloak city in Imperial armor, or an Empire-controlled city in Stormcloak armor, you can be charged by the guards (you'd get a bounty of 40 gold, I think). I'd like to know:

- Does this also apply to specific city guard armor such as Whiterun armor or Haafingar armor?
- Are there other clothes you could be punished for, such as vampire clothes in all cities, or Thalmor clothes and Elven armor in Stormcloak cities?

All in all, which clothes exactly in what cities are punishable? Does anyone know? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can remember, there is not such thing in vanilla Skyrim. There are some mods wich implements such behaviour. You may look at this old question https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36346/does-the-faction-of-your-armor-clothes-affect-character-interactions-in-skryim

Comment: @RickStarrunner I remember that once long ago some Windhelm guards charged me for a bounty for no reason, probably because I was wearing Empire-soldier/-guard armor but I don't remember exactly, it's too long ago. But elsewhere someone stated that the clothes you wear may deserve you a bounty.

Comment: @JeanEstelSeptim guards may make some comments about it, same when you are not wearing any clothing at all for example, but there won't be any bounty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can wear any armor in any city without repercussions in unmodded Skyrim. Hold guards will comment if you wear the armor of the opposing faction, but will not place a bounty on your character.

At worst, guards will say something along the lines of "You dare strut around here, wearing that filthy Stormcloak hide?" or "For your sake, I hope you took that armor from a dead Imperial scout..."

You'll get similarly snarky comments if you wear Thieves Guild armor or are a member of the Dark Brotherhood. Still, the game is very forgiving and you will never be punished for wearing a specific faction's gear.

You can read the comments that hold guards say about your equipment by [following this link](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Guard_Dialogue#Reactions_to_Player.27s_Equipment)

In your case you may have been seen stealing something, trespassing, or committing another minor crime which caused the guard to investigate you. In fact, you may have been witnessed breaking the law days earlier and only just now came close enough to a guard to be accosted by them

Comment: Thank you. I've always been worried about wearing something I might be charged for. While I have no idea what I had been charged for, it really is a long time and maybe you're right.